# Avoiding Out-Of-Ram Crashes in unity

Tags: unity, memory-efficiency

My Players experience crashes on older computers when they enter a scene with a lots of 3d models.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this, except deleting those models from the scene?

Comment: We'll need more details about your project to be able to suggest ways to reduce RAM use. Have you done some profiling to identify the biggest RAM hogs in your game, or to spot places where you might be leaking memory (ie. RAM use increasing over a window of time when you don't expect to be loading/creating new content / RAM remaining occupied after you've ostensibly eliminated the content)? Watch for things like textures (especially RenderTextures), instantiated copies of assets (eg. anytime you modify a material, texture, or mesh at runtime), and assets you load dynamically but don't dispose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can add more; but the big things you can do are:

- Have lower res models. This is how games ran a dozen years ago (or two dozen!), so have lower poly-count models. Often 3dsMax and other programs can even *generate* a lower poly model for you
- Have 2d versions of the model when it's far enough. This is extremely common for Trees and things, but interestingly you can do this with models. The Total War series does this noticeably.
- Add "fog" closer to you (or don't load things outside of a radius.) This is also made famous games when they overused this and only loaded things right in front of you (N64 superman if I recall)
- Lower-res textures. Textures are often a culprit for very high Ram usage.

Comment: Thank you :-)
It appears it was not the VRAM but the a Windows 10 Update which broke the GPU driver files.

PS: N64 Superman? You mean this masterpiece? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dJXgJ1c4vY

Comment: Ha! Indeed, and I was thinking of AVGN when I mentioned it. Though it turns out it was Cybermorph that had the really-close loading of terrain and such: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmtAjrHwFek Superman 64 happens to demonstrate the close-up fog pretty well though